# How do I read the Id for an object instantiated by my @testSetup method?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I've setup a `@testSetup` method to share amongst my Unit Test methods. One of my methods relies on the auto-incremented Id of the object created by my test method. Here's my code:

```
@testSetup 
static void testSetup() {
    Campaign campaign = new Campaign();
    campaign.Name = 'test campaign';
    insert campaign;

    FundsRequest__c request = new FundsRequest__c();
    request.TotalCost__c = 10000.00;

    insert request;
}

@IsTest
static void getCosts_validFundRequestIdProvided_hydratedObjectReturned() {
    ...
    // Act
    FundsRequestController.RequestTotals totals = FundsRequestController.getCosts(request.Id);
    // Assert
    ...
}
```

I get compilation errors when I try to change the return value for `testSetup()` from void : **Error:(22, 35) Test setup method must return void**

Comment: You should query campaign before act, Like
FundsRequest__c req = [SELECT Id FROM FundsRequest__c LIMIT 1];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful explanation about the design and its intended benefits is posted in this comment to [Remember static variables set during testSetup annotated methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC) by the then product manager:

> We intentionally clear out static variables between each test method. 
>   If we did not, each test would cease to be an independent trial. You
>   could modify the static in one test method, which would make the order
>   in which tests operate relevant to the results.  This is precisely
>   what you don't want - data dependent tests.
>
> If you want information that is common to all tests, it can be
>   inserted in the test setup method and queried in each test method. 
>   The idea here is not to reduce the number of SOQL queries, it is to
>   reduce the amount of data being inserted into the system.  If you
>   insert 1000 records in test setup, run fifteen test methods, and you
>   run a query 15 times to get the 1000 records each time, that's still
>   less expensive (and faster) than inserting 1000 records 15 times.

As test methods are `static` and the aim is to run the `@TestSetup` once only `static` variables would be the only way to share references.

If you don't like having to query, there is nothing to stop you defining your own non-`@TestSetup` static method that returns a value and calling that from each `@IsTest` method. If you are not setting up a lot of data, a small reduction in speed might be more than made up for in by the cleanness of the test code.

Answer (score 3):

`@testSetup` method will return `void`.

To retrieve the records created from testSetup, you have to query explicitly based on the way you have created those records.

For example, to retrieve Campaign Id use,

`[SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Name = 'test campaign']`, since you have created Campaign Record with a name `'test campaign'`

Comment: This is the only way? This seems brittle... In my case, I don't have a `Name` field on the object I need (nor is `Name` guaranteed to be  unique). Any suggestion of a more reliable and direct way to refer to a specific record?

Comment: how you are inserting records ?

Comment: @IanTunbridge You have to understand that in a unit test context, only a restricted list of records are visible.By default a unit test has an annotation (SeeAllData=False), which means you don't have access to existing records (best practise by the way !). So you're going to need a way to identify your record. If you insert only one record and the triggers don't add up some, you're going to be fine by querying them